# Why this two different implementations of Tuple have a different size?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, tuples, variadic-templates

I have two different implementations of a Tuple class template. One with specialization for any number of arguments and one using variadic templates. When using an empty class for some of the tuple elements the two implementations have different sizes. Why does the second one using a variadic template have a bigger size and is it possible to be fixed to have the same size as the first one?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Nil {};

template <typename T1 = Nil, typename T2 = Nil>
struct Tuple1 : Tuple1<T2>
{
  T1 x;

  using Base = Tuple1<T2>;

  Base* base() { return static_cast<Base*>(this); }
  const Base* base() const { return static_cast<const Base*>(this); }

  Tuple1(const T1& t1, const T2& t2)
    : Base{ t2 }, x{ t1 } {}
};

template <> struct Tuple1<> {};

template <typename T1>
struct Tuple1<T1> : Tuple1<>
{
  T1 x;

  using Base = Tuple1<>;

  Base* base() { return static_cast<Base*>(this); }
  const Base* base() const { return static_cast<const Base*>(this); }

  Tuple1(const T1& t1)
    : Base{}, x{ t1 } {}
};

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

template <typename...> struct Tuple2;

template <> struct Tuple2<> {};

template <typename Head, typename... Tail>
struct Tuple2<Head, Tail...> : Tuple2<Tail...>
{
  Tuple2(const Head& head, const Tail&... tail)
    : Base{ tail... }, m_head{ head } {}

private:
  using Base = Tuple2<Tail...>;
  Head m_head;
};

int main()
{
  cout << "Tuple1 sizes:\n";
  cout << sizeof(Tuple1<>) << '\n';
  cout << sizeof(Tuple1<int*>) << '\n';
  cout << sizeof(Tuple1<int*, Nil>) << '\n';

  cout << '\n';

  cout << "Tuple2 sizes:\n";
  cout << sizeof(Tuple2<>) << '\n';
  cout << sizeof(Tuple2<int*>) << '\n';
  cout << sizeof(Tuple2<int*, Nil>) << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

The result of the execution of the program with MSVC 2022 is the following:

```
Tuple1 sizes:
1
8
8

Tuple2 sizes:
1
8
16
```

Comment: `Tuple1<int*, Nil>` instantiates `Tuple1<T1>` specialization (which is really `Tuple1<T1, Nil>`), not the general template. It doesn't have a member of type `Nil`.

Comment: To do the same for `Tuple2`, you need a specialization that avoids carrying a `Nil` member. [Something like this](https://godbolt.org/z/be8sh9ahK0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Tuple1<int*>` is `Tuple1<int*, Nil>` and have a specialization wich unique member `T1 x;` with empty base class `Tuple1<Nil, Nil>`.

On the other side, `Tuple2` treat `Nil` as any other (empty) types.

With [cppinsights](https://cppinsights.io/s/769e7da7), you might see instantiation:

```
template<>
struct Tuple2<Nil> : public Tuple2<>
{
  inline Tuple2(const Nil& head);

private: 
  using Base = Tuple2<>;
  Nil m_head;
};


template<>
struct Tuple2<int *, Nil> : public Tuple2<Nil>
{
  inline Tuple2(int *const& head, const Nil& __tail1);

private: 
  using Base = Tuple2<Nil>;
  int* m_head;
};
```

so `Tuple2<int *, Nil>` has 2 members:

- `int* m_head;`
- `Nil Tuple2<Nil>::m_head`.

Comment: Could you propose a fix for Tuple2 to has the same size as Tuple1?

Comment: Add extra specialization: `template <> struct Tuple2<Nil>{};`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use MSVC's undocumented `/d1reportAllClassLayout` option to see how it lays out the classes.

```
class Tuple2<int *,struct Nil>  size(16):
    +---  
 0  | +--- (base class Tuple2<struct Nil>)  
 0  | | +--- (base class Tuple2<>)  
    | | +---  
 0  | | Nil m_head  
    | +---      
    | <alignment member> (size=7)  
 8  | m_head    
    +---
```

So, `Tuple2<int *, Nil>` has two `m_head` members -

- it's own, and
- one from the base class `Tuple2<Nil>`.

In contrast, the below shows that `Tuple1<int*,Nil>` has a single member `x` with an empty base class.

```
class Tuple1<int *,struct Nil>  size(8):
    +---  
 0  | +--- (base class Tuple1<struct Nil,struct Nil>)   
    | +--- 
 0  | x     
    +---
```